# Proper way to conditional listing in react-native by using radio button?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

From external server, the app receives some list like this.

```
[ 
{'type' : 'fruits', 'name' : 'banana'}, 
{'type' : 'fruits', 'name' : 'apple'},
{'type' : 'vegetables', 'name' : 'carrot'},
{'type' : 'vegetables', 'name' :'onion'}   
]
```

and then I will save it to redux store to use this in some component through `mapStateToProps`.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        foodList: state.foodList
    }
};
```

now I can use this by `this.props.foodList`

What I am trying to do is there are some radio buttons (all, fruits, vegetables). If I click the button, the proper list should showing up. Simply (all button => all list, fruits button => fruits list).

How can I do this?

I tried to add if statement to `this.props.foodList.map(...)`, but there was some syntax problem. I don't need to retreive data from the server again. How can I do that simply?

---

```
class someComponent extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       selectedIndex: 0
    }
}

render() {

   return(

    <RadioGroup
    selectedIndex={0}
    onSelect = { (index)=> this.setState({selectedIndex : index}) }
    >

        <RadioButton value={0}>
           <Text>All</Text>
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton value={1}>
           <Text>Fruits</Text>
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton value={2}>
            <Text>Vegetables</Text>
        </RadioButton>

    </RadioGroup>

    <View>
        <Text>Food List</Text>
        <List>
            {
                this.props.foodList.map((l, i) => (
                   <ListItem
                       key= {i}
                       title= {l.name}
                       subtitle = {l.type}
                   />
                ))
            }
        </List>
    </View>
)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of storing the `index`, store the `type` in `state` variable, like either type will be `'all' or 'fruits' or 'vegetables'`, like this:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       type: 'all'
    }
}

<RadioButton value='all'>
   <Text>All</Text>
</RadioButton>

<RadioButton value='fruits'>
   <Text>Fruits</Text>
</RadioButton>

<RadioButton value='vegetables'>
    <Text>Vegetables</Text>
</RadioButton>
```

By this way it will be easy to use `map`, and create the list `dynamically`.

Now call a `function` from `render` method, that will `return` the list elements, like this:

```
<View>
    <Text>Food List</Text>
    <List>
      { this.renderList() }
    </List>
</View>

renderList(){
    return this.props.foodList.map((el, i) => {
        if(this.state.type == 'all' || el.type == this.state.type)
            return  <ListItem
                        key= {i}
                        title= {el.name}
                        subtitle = {el.type}
                    />
        else
          return null;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store a selected type and then filter out in the map using the if condition like

```
class someComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           selectedType: 'all',
        }
    }
    var typeMap = ['all', 'fruits', 'vegetables'];

    render() {

       return(

        <RadioGroup
        selectedIndex={0}
        onSelect = { (index)=> this.setState({selectedType : this.typeMap[index]}) }
        >

            <RadioButton value={0}>
               <Text>All</Text>
            </RadioButton>

            <RadioButton value={1}>
               <Text>Fruits</Text>
            </RadioButton>

            <RadioButton value={2}>
                <Text>Vegetables</Text>
            </RadioButton>

        </RadioGroup>

        <View>
            <Text>Food List</Text>
            <List>
                {
                    this.props.foodList.map((list, i) =>  {
                      if(this.state.selectedType === 'all' || this.state.selectedType === list.type )
                      return ( <ListItem
                           key= {i}
                           title= {l.name}
                           subtitle = {l.type}
                       />
                    )
                    else 
                      return null;
                  }      
                }
            </List>
        </View>
    )
    }

}
```